# ADFS Login Page Works but calling from RP fails

Tags: authentication, wif, adfs

We have configured RP as my application with ADFS server. When I try login with ADFS login page separately with following URL https://<>/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx, user credentials work. When we invoke from our client application, we are presented with ADFS login page. Post entering credentials we are presented with "Error Occurred" with Activity Id that is GUID. What may be the issue. Kindly guide.

Comment: When we analyzed event viewer we found following entry for same.  "System.ArgumentException: ID4216: The ClaimType 'UserName' must be of format 'namespace'/'name'." Am not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look in the Event Viewer on the server under "Applications and Services Logs" / "AD FS" / Admin.

That will give you a more detailed error message.

Comment: When we analyzed event viewer we found following entry for same. "System.ArgumentException: ID4216: The ClaimType 'UserName' must be of format 'namespace'/'name'." Am not sure how to resolve this. – Saravanan 25 secs ago   edit

Answer (score 0):

And if the answer by @nzpcmad does not give you enough information, you can right click the '`Admin`' node, go to '`View`' and enable '`Show Analytics and Debug Logs`'.

This will show another node called '`AD FS Tracing`' under the '`Applications and Services Logs`'. Right click the '`Debug`' sub-node and click '`Enable Log`'. Then repro the issue and refresh the view to see the ADFS trace logs.